# Can I ignore errors in my ssh config?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm running an ubuntu image in a docker container, with my .ssh directory mounted from my native MacOs environment.

My .ssh/config file contains

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_common
```

This works fine on a mac, but AddKeysToAgent and UseKeychain are not valid for linux, and anything (e.g. git) that uses the openssh-client package won't just ignore the unrecognised directives, but fail and exit.

Is there any way of having a .ssh/config file that will let me share it across mac and linux?

Comment: I suggest that a better title for this question is "Can i make some entries in ssh config conditional to platform to enable mac+linux sharing?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `Match` keyword in the [ssh config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) file to restrict a portion of the configuration to only apply under certain conditions.  For the excerpt in the question, something like the following should work:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_common

Match exec "uname -s | grep Darwin"
    UseKeychain yes
```

On a linux system, the `grep` will return failure (1), and so the following line(s) will be ignored; on the Mac host, the grep will return success (0) and the `UseKeychain yes` line will be applied.

The `Match` block is terminated by the next `Match`, `Host`, or end of file.

Note that `AddKeysToAgent` is not platform-specific, but is available in OpenSSH since version 7.2, so presumably you are using an older version of OpenSSH in the Ubuntu container but not on the Mac host.

Comment: should you use `grep -q` here?

Comment: @Joshua the command from the `exec` will be run with its stdout redirected to `/dev/null`, so I don't think that makes a difference. But this answer doesn't seem to work, anyways. It will complain about the unknown directive irrespective of whether the `Match` condition succeeded or failed. Moreover, if the condition is `Match exec "sleep 30; exit 19"`, it will dutifully sleep 30 seconds, *then* complain about any unknown directive and die ;-)

Comment: @MEHColeman could you please mention the exact version of ubuntu and ssh where this worked; I'm just not able to make it work with any version of openssh -- not even the last openssh-portable. But maybe the ubuntu people have some special patches for it.

Comment: @mosvy Aah, I unconsciously fixed an error with the answer above - the Match keyword should be indented as the other keywords are. This works on ubuntu 18:04. I have openssh-client (1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3) installed. The other answer here also works perfectly)

Comment: [@mosvy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529024/181036) is the correct response.  I'd delete this one, but I can't delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

You should use the `IgnoreUnknown` directive early on in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
IgnoreUnknown   UseKeychain,AddKeysToAgent
```

From the `ssh_config(5)` manpage:

> `IgnoreUnknown`
>
> Specifies a pattern-list of unknown options to be ignored if they are encountered in configuration parsing.  This may be used to suppress errors if `ssh_config` contains options that are unrecognised by `ssh(1)`.  It is recommended that `IgnoreUnknown` be listed early in the configuration file as it will not be applied to unknown options that appear before it.

---

On all versions of `openssh` I could test, a failing `Match` condition will **not** prevent `ssh` from erroring out on any following directives unknown to it:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Match !all
        Foobar yes
$ ssh localhost
/home2/ahq/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: foobar
/home2/ahq/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Comment: This answer also works perfecty. Thanks!